# How do I define an SVG doc under <defs>, and reuse with the <use> tag?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <svg id="importeddoc">...</svg>
    </defs>
    <use x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="#importeddoc"></use>
</svg>
```

I would think that a sub portion of my original SVG document would appear in a box 100x100. But instead nothing happens. From the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement) it looks like this should work. Any pointers?

---

Turns out it was the the d3.js library to construct my image and it snips off namespaces for some reason. I had to do `.attr("xlink:xlink:href", "...")` to get it to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add all namespace declarations to the `svg` element, it should indeed be possible to reference the embedded SVG. The following example produces the output shown below. This works in all browsers I tested, and in Batik Squiggle as well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">      
  <defs>
    <svg id="importeddoc">
      <rect width="2cm" height="1cm"/>
      <circle cx="1cm" cy="5mm" r="3mm" fill="red"/>
    </svg>
  </defs>
  <use x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="#importeddoc"/>
  <use x="0" y="60" width="40" height="20" transform="scale(1.5, 1)" xlink:href="#importeddoc"/>
</svg>
```

[image]

If it doesn't work for you, what SVG viewer do you use?

Comment: Tis was exactly it - I was using the d3.js library to construct my image and it snips off namespaces for some reason. I had to do `.attr("xlink:xlink:href", "...")` to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: Same here. This looks like a bug in d3.js.

Comment: dsummersl, you're a lifesaver!